# nodejs .env variable showing undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, dotenv

I use dotenv to separate my bot tokens from the app itself. However, when I run the code it shows the env variables as undefined and as a result throws an error: `Error: An invalid token was provided.`

Here is the code requiring dotenv

```
require('dotenv').config()
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const {Client, Attachment, RichEmbed} = require("discord.js");
```

Here's the code calling the variable and the console.log where I attempted debug

```
console.log(process.env.BOT_TOKEN); // Display token test
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN); // Login Token
```

Finally here is the config.env file itself

```
DEV_TOKEN="Not trying to leak the token"
BOT_TOKEN="Not trying to leak the token"
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: You just need `require('dotenv')` , remove `.config()`

Comment: @Raymond No, you **do** need `.config()`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create `.env` file, not `config.env`

Comment: None of the many answers does resolve my issue, which is the same as the latter: (the information, retrieved from the .env file is treated as undefined). What I am trying to do is to connect to mysql database.Just for the record, I will say, that this works perfectly well, without the .env file, but only with the information required for authentication inserted into the app.js file. I have tried unsuccessfully any of the posted answers. Also I have tried to show the version of the dotenv from the console.log(dotenv.MY_ENV_VAR); which again, showed undefined What could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Quote marks aren't required in the `.env` file. Could you try removing them and seeing if it works (with no space after the equals sign)?